# Netty EmbeddedChannel simulating two distinct connections

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am using Netty's [EmbeddedChannel](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) in order to test some of my handlers.

I have a use case where i want to test that my handler distinguishes between two connections( channels ), based on their [#remoteAddress()](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#147).

Unfortunately, [EmbeddedChannel](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) uses [EmbeddedSocketAddress](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedSocketAddress.html), which provides a hard-coded value, for every channel created. Hence, two different [EmbeddedChannel](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) instances have the exact same [#remoteAddress()](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#147).

I have tried to **Spy** the EmbeddedChannel and mock out the remoteAddress method, but because of the EmbeddedChannel implementation this does not apply as the [ChannelPipeline](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.html#113) is created before the mocking takes place. Hence, the mocked value is not passed on the pipeline, as it has a reference to the non-mocked object.

Is there any alternative on how to achieve the above. Ideally i would like two different instances of [EmbeddedChannel](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) to have different [#remoteAddress()](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/channel/Channel.html#147).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use the id of the channel ?

see http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.html#id()

Of course this will lead to not behave as your current code based on remote Address. However basing only on remote Address could be not enough in some cases (for instance if the real remote is behind a proxy). So maybe you could consider id in "normal" situation too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom channel that extends `EmbeddedChannel`, then override `protected SocketAddress remoteAddress0()` to return the address you want.

Something like this should do

```
public class CustomEmbeddedChannel extends EmbeddedChannel{

    private InetSocketAddress socketAddress;

    public CustomEmbeddedChannel(String host, int port, final ChannelHandler ... handlers){
        super(handlers);
        socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    }

    @Override
    protected SocketAddress remoteAddress0(){
        return this.socketAddress;
    }
}
```